# Javascript: the most efficient way to check if a variable is a function, an array or a object

Tags: javascript

Let's suppose we have a variable that could be a function, object or array.

I want to find the most efficient way to determinate it.

I think the following way is not optimized because if I know that `isFunction = true` I don't want to calculate the other variables (isArray, isObject);

What is the order to calculate them, which optimize the resources, 
by using the ternary operation?

```
var isFunction,
    isArray,
    isObject;

var obj = function () {};

isFunction = (typeof obj === "function") ? true : false;
isArray = (obj.length > 0) ? true : false;
isObject = (typeof obj === "object") ? true : false;

console.log(isFunction , isArray , isObject ); // true, false, false (the good way)
console.log(isFunction , isArray , isObject ); // true, undefined, undefined
```

Comment: Why do you think that `[]` isn't an array?  Also, you don't need `? true : false`.

Comment: `undefined`, `null`, `< 1`, `NaN` are all equals `false` when `Boolean` parse. I don't understand what you want... Please be more specific.

Comment: Why is it that you need to know? JavaScript is not a strongly-typed language. Why not just check situationally and make sure an object *looks like* the sort of object you expect?

Comment: Also you're performing those relational comparisons, and they return boolean values already, so using the "? :" operator is pointless.

Comment: To check for a true array, you should use `obj instanceof Array`.

Comment: In JS, everything is an object.

Comment: @graphicdivine: `null` and `undefined` are crappy objects though - they don't even have properties.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is as "efficient" as I can make it. It's short, but readable, and should do the job correctly. It will be performant in modern browsers that have a native implementation of `some`, and the nature of `some` is such that it only executes the callback until one of the items in the array meets the condition.

Just make sure you add in [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for older browsers.

```
function isOneOf(obj, types) {
  var type;
  type = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj);
  return types.split(' ').some(function (t) {
    return type.indexOf(t) > -1;
  });
}

isOneOf({}, 'Array Object Function');
```

This should work for `Array`, `Date`, `Error`, `Function`, `Null`, `Number`, `Object`, `String`, and `Undefined`. I haven't done thorough cross-browser testing with all those types, so make sure to do some good unit-testing before taking my word for it.

Answer (score 0):

The following functions are ways how the dojo toolkit tests for arrays, functions, etc

```
isString = function(it){
    return (typeof it == "string" || it instanceof String); // Boolean
},

isArray = function(it){
    return it && (it instanceof Array || typeof it == "array"); // Boolean
},

isFunction = function(it){
    return opts.call(it) === "[object Function]";
},

isObject = function(it){
    return it !== undefined &&
        (it === null || typeof it == "object" || lang.isArray(it) || lang.isFunction(it)); // Boolean
},

isArrayLike = function(it){
    return it && it !== undefined && // Boolean
        // keep out built-in constructors (Number, String, ...) which have length
        // properties
        !lang.isString(it) && !lang.isFunction(it) &&
        !(it.tagName && it.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'form') &&
        (lang.isArray(it) || isFinite(it.length));
},
```

I don't see the point of trying to optimize this kind of code. If you really cared about optimizations, you should probably use simpler non-overloaded functions where these checks are not necessary.